# Overheating and fan noise problem on a Toshiba Portege R830-13C

Tags: 11.10, laptop, fan, overheating

I have an overheating and excessive fan noise problem with Ubuntu 11.10 on a brand new Toshiba Portege R830-13C laptop. The laptop is dual boot with Windows 7, where I don't have this problem at all, so I'm assuming it's an Ubuntu issue. Any ideas?

Comment: I've looked into this myself. As far as I know, it is just an ongoing bug with the 11.10 release--I saw that stated 3 days ago. It happens to my laptop also...this is the first distro version that it's done it with :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue with the Active State Power Management (ASPM) in the kernel for Ubuntu 11.10 that effects some laptops - details in this [Phoronix article](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux_2638_aspm&num=1) .

You can edit your GRUB cofig file and add some parameters to try to solve the issue;

1. From a terminal (or after pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>) run:

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```

   and enter your password.
2. Find the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and append `i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 i915.i915_enable_fbc=1 pcie_aspm=force quiet splash` to its end. For example:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 i915.i915_enable_fbc=1 pcie_aspm=force quiet splash"
   ```

   Save the file and close the editor.
3. Finally, start a terminal and run:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

   to update GRUB's configuration file (you will need to enter your password).

**Warning**

If pcie_aspm=force is set, hardware that does not support ASPM can cause the system to stop responding. Before setting pcie_aspm=force, ensure that all PCIe hardware on the system supports ASPM.